# Объединение двух видео

Tags: android, java, ffmpeg

Не могу разобраться с этим [кодом](https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264). Что мне с ним делать, чтобы я мог объединить два видео?

Comment: @eldqs, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: В первую очередь нужно разобраться с NDK.

Comment: @metalurgus, да я даже не понял, что делать, после того как я его скачаю.

Comment: может кто нибудь подсказать как мне с ним работать или предложить другую библиотеку

Answer (score 1):

> Что мне с ним делать, чтобы я мог
> объединить два видео?

Если просто с помощью **ffmpeg** и командной строки объединить видео, то можно использовать параметр **concat**.

Например, объединяем несколько эпизодов из DVD-диска в один файл, чтобы потом сконвертировать их в какой-нибудь другой формат.

```
ffmpeg -i concat:"VTS_02_1.VOB|VTS_02_2.VOB|VTS_02_3.VOB" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "VIDEO.VOB"
```

Comment: @nikolja я даже не могу разобраться, как его импортировать, написано скачать или клонировать гитом, но что делать дальше, не понял. Могли бы ли вы оъяснить мне, о чем он?